# Can boosting the Caddx vista to 1200mw cause damage to the unit?

Tags: safety, fpv-goggles

What can happen to your Caddx Vista camera if you boost its output to 1200mW? Could it be damaged in any way; including overheating?

Comment: Do you mean will 1200mW output cook the Caddx Vista from excessive heating?

Comment: No, I mean what can happen; meaning all possibilities,  including excess heating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, after doing some digging, There are a few things to consider when boosting a Caddx Vista to 1200mw. First, the Caddx Vista tends to get hotter that the DJI air unit, so heat is one thing to consider. If the drone is flying, there should be enough airflow to dissipate the heat, so 1200mw shouldn't cause any overheating issues. Just make sure the drone isn't sitting somewhere with the Vista on a high-power setting.

Another thing that seems to happen when using a higher power setting (whether that be 1200mw or just 1000mw) is that the bit rate drops. Several people claim that when flying with 1000/1200mw, the bit rate drops and causes lower image quality.

See here starting with post #84 on [page 6](https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?3501605-Caddx-Vista-HD-DJI-FPV/page6) and then the beginning of [page 7](https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?3501605-Caddx-Vista-HD-DJI-FPV/page7).

Comment: Thank you for your response. That makes sense, I'll give it try once I have the parts myself and confirm